# (Gatsby) Easiest way to diverge from the `SEO.defaultProps` on a per-document basis?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Most of the pages on my website are in Norwegian—

```
Seo.defaultProps = {
  lang: `no`,
  ...
}
```

Some articles, however, are in English.

I use some automatic CSS hyphenation on my website. Thus, I need to set the HTML `lang` to English in the `head` of these documents so that the words break properly.

I'm not interested in building a full-scale multilingual site. I just want to be able to diverge from the default language property on a per-document basis.

What's the absolute easiest way to do this? Do I need to change my `gatsby-node.js` file? Or could I set my `template.js` file to ask for a `lang` within each MDX file? Or could I maybe insert an `seo-english.js` component within the articles I wish to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it easiest to use `Helmet` in those posts in which I wished to diverge from the default props.

```
<Helmet
    htmlAttributes={{
        lang: 'en'
    }}
/>
```